# How can I replace '&amp;' with '&' in XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm really stuck at replacing `'&amp;'` with '&' in XML file.

I want to change this

```
<Content>The &amp;#x3A9; &amp;lt;product name&amp;gt;</Content>
```

into that

```
<Content>The &#x3A9; &lt;product name&gt;</Content>
```

Is there a way to change it using replace function ? if not, are there alternatives ?

Thank you

Comment: In a text editor? programmatically?

Comment: Are you sure that all the double-escaped references are either character references or built-in XML entities (lt, gt, amp, quot or apos)?  If you have other entities in there such as HTML ones (`&amp;eacute;`) then a naïve approach will result in output that is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Content">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<Content>The &#x3A9; &lt;product name&gt;</Content>
```